I cant get mapbox to work in my NextJs project
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
// eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
// @ts-ignore
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import Image from 'next/image';
import moment from 'moment';
import { MAP_STYLES, CONFIG_MAP } from '@/components/MapContainer/config';

import styles from './styles.module.scss';

interface MapProps {
  config: any;
  heatmap: any;
}

interface MapInfo {
  sourceId: string;
  layerId: any;
  data: any;
  config: any;
  urlObj: any;
}

export const MapContainer: React.FC<MapProps> = ({ config, heatmap }) => {
  const defaultCenter = [-84.45, 33.76];
  const defaultZoom = 10;
  const center = heatmap?.center || defaultCenter;
  const mapContainer = useRef<any>(null);
  const map = useRef<mapboxgl.Map | any>(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(center[0]);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(center[1]);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(config?.zoom_level || defaultZoom);
  const [mapStyle, setMapStyle] = useState(MAP_STYLES[0].style);
  const [mapInfo, setMapInfo] = useState<MapInfo[]>([]);
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Map instance:', map.current);

    if (mapContainer.current && !map.current) {
      mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_TOKEN as string;
      map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: mapStyle,
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
      });

      map.current.on('load', () => {
        heatmap?.data?.forEach((data: any, index: any) => {
          loadGeoJson(data, index);
        });

        map.current?.addControl(
            new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
              positionOptions: {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
              },
              trackUserLocation: true,
              showUserHeading: true,
            }),
        );
        map.current?.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
      });
      map.current.on('move', () => {
        if(map.current) {
        setLng(map.current.getCenter().lng);
        setLat(map.current.getCenter().lat);
        setZoom(map.current.getZoom());
        }
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (map.current) {
        map.current.remove();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) {
      map.current.setStyle(mapStyle);
    }
  }, [mapStyle]);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  };

  const handleStyleChange = (style: string) => {
    setMapStyle(style);
    setIsMenuOpen(false);
  };

  const parseDate = (inputDate: any) => {
    const cleanedDate = inputDate.replace(/<br\/>/g, '').trim();
    return moment(cleanedDate, 'Do MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  };

  const parseTime = (inputTime: any) => {
    return moment(inputTime, 'h A').format('HH');
  };


  const loadGeoJson = async (config: any, layerId: any) => {
    try {
      console.log('Loading GeoJSON data:', config?.url);
      const response = await fetch(config?.url);
      if (!response.ok) {
        new Error(`Error loading GeoJSON data: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      const {uniqueSourceId} = configureMap(map, data, layerId, config);
      const _mapInfo = [...mapInfo, {
        sourceId: uniqueSourceId,
        layerId: layerId,
        data: data,
        config: config,
        urlObj: config?.url,
      }];
      setMapInfo(_mapInfo);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading GeoJSON data:', error);
    }
  };

  const configureMap = (map: mapboxgl.Map, data: any, layerId: any, conf: any) => {
    const uniqueLayerId = `cluster-layer-${layerId}`;
    const uniqueSourceId = `cluster-source-${layerId}`;
    config.functions.forEach((func: any) => {
      const {name, layerType = "clustered", args} = func;
      // @ts-ignore
      CONFIG_MAP[name]({args, map, data, layerType, layerId, uniqueLayerId, uniqueSourceId}, conf);
    });

    return {
      uniqueSourceId,
      uniqueLayerId,
    };
  };

  return (
      <main className={styles['custom-map-container']}>
        <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
          <div ref={mapContainer} className='w-full h-full'/>
          <div className='absolute bottom-4 right-4 flex items-center'>
            <div className='relative'>
              <button
                  className={`bg-[#b0b0b0] text-white p-1  flex items-center space-x-2 flex-col ${
                      isMenuOpen ? 'rounded-tr-md rounded-br-md' : 'rounded'
                  }`}
                  onClick={toggleMenu}
                  style={{fontSize: '10px'}}
              >
              <span>
                <Image
                    src={MAP_STYLES[0].icon}
                    alt={MAP_STYLES[0].name}
                    className='w-10 h-10 cursor-pointer'
                    onClick={() => handleStyleChange(MAP_STYLES[0].style)}
                />
              </span>
                <span className='text-center'>Streets</span>
                {isMenuOpen && (
                    <div
                        className='absolute right-full top-0 mr-2 bg-[#b0b0b0] p-1  flex space-x-2 rounded-tl-md rounded-bl-md'>
                      {MAP_STYLES.slice(1).map(({style, name, icon}) => (
                          <div key={style} className='flex flex-col items-center'>
                      <span className='flex items-center justify-center w-10 h-10'>
                        <Image
                            src={icon}
                            alt={name}
                            className='w-full h-full object-contain cursor-pointer'
                            onClick={() => handleStyleChange(style)}
                        />
                      </span>
                            <span className='text-white text-center text-[10px]'>{name}</span>
                          </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='ml-auto align-items-center flex text-sm mt-1 mb-3'>
            Longitude: {lng?.toFixed(2)} | Latitude: {lat?.toFixed(2)} | Zoom: {zoom?.toFixed(2)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
  );
};

Above is my complete code
There is no error in the console however, when logging the MapInstance it is logging two times and first time it is getting null and then second time it is providing the map instance.
I have tried different things. however was unable to resolve this issue.
I have tried to modify the webpack to handle loading worker files which I don't think should be neccessary anyway but that didn't work either.
If you have any idea, help would be much appreciated :)

There isn't any issue with using Mapbox with NextJS. I would recommend simplifying your code down to a basic 'show a map on the page' and work your way back from there.
If you provide a reproduction of the error you are seeing or a link to a codesandbox with your repository, it's more likely some one may take the time to wade through your code.

Hi Andrew, Thank you for your input. Since, I debug and found that the map.current was not being set to null. during the cleanup in the useEffect.
Thank you for your response.
I will remember to have the reproduction of my code if I receive any other error
